# MYSQL (MariaDB) calculated percentage column on update

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to achieve a calculated (virtual?) column that updates on an insert so as not to use a trigger, cross joins or CTEs. What I'm hoping to do is group by one field (Col1) and calculate the given row's percentage of the total on the table. For example:

`+------+-----+------+
| Col1 | Amt | Pct  |
+------+-----+------+
| foo  |  10 |  0.5 |
| foo  |   5 | 0.25 |
| bar  |  15 |    1 |
| foo  |   5 | 0.25 |
+------+-----+------+`

New row inserted ... `{Col1: bar, Amt: 5}`

`+------+-----+------+
| Col1 | Amt | Pct  |
+------+-----+------+
| foo  |  10 |  0.5 |
| foo  |   5 | 0.25 |
| bar  |  15 | 0.75 |
| foo  |   5 | 0.25 |
| bar  |   5 | 0.25 |
+------+-----+------+`

Any help is appreciated. I've tried searching the various posts including forks and haven't found a virtual column way of approaching this on MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

The values in each row of a computed column cannot depend on values in other rows of the table.

You may wish to consider a view rather than a computed column. This is the definition of the view. Notice that it takes the sum of all the amounts.

```
SELECT a.Col1, a.Amt,  
       (100.0 * A.Amt / B.Tot) Pct
  FROM tbl a
  JOIN (SELECT SUM(Amt) Tot FROM tbl)
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, and if true it would explain my difficulty in something so simple that is available on other platforms. I know I can do something external such as a view but that isn't the goal.